# Checking if a photo is present in a set or not(Flickr4Java)

Tags: java, flickr

I want to know how to check whether a photo is in a photoset or not. I got the photo through

```
 PhotoList<Photo> PL = Pface.recentlyUpdated(thisDate, null, 0, 0);
 for (int i = 0;i<PL.size();i++)
 {
   Photo p = PL.get(i); //want to check that if 'p' is present in any set or not . If present want to get the name.
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this helped me in getting through this.

https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/blob/master/Flickr4Java/src/examples/java/Backup.java

Answer (score 0):

referring to the photo.java file from https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/blob/master/Flickr4Java/src/main/java/com/flickr4java/flickr/photos/Photo.java

I see that every photo object has an ID.

So if you have two photosets: photoSet1 and photoSet2 where photoOne is a photo object from photoSet1, you can do something like:

```
boolean photoFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < photoSet2.size(); i++)
{
    if (photoOne.id.Equals( photoSet2.Get(i).id ) )
    {
        photoFound = true;
    }
}
```